# How to get json in jquery sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-ui-sortable

My code is like this :

HTML Code :

```
<form action="example3_action.php" name="example3" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id='serialize_output' name="serialize_output">
    <div class='span4'>
        box 1 (Customer)
        <ol class='nested_with_switch test1 vertical'>
            <li data-id="1" data-name='Valentino Rossi'>Valentino Rossi</li>
            <li data-id="2" data-name='David Beckham'>David Beckham</li>
            <li data-id="3" data-name='Eden Hazard'>Eden Hazard</li>
            <li data-id="4" data-name='Lionel Messi'>Lionel Messi</li>
            <li data-id="5" data-name='Christiano Ronaldo'>Christiano Ronaldo</li>
            <li data-id="6" data-name='Frank Lampard'>Frank Lampard</li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div class='span4'>
        box 2 (Room Type)
        <ol class='nested_with_switch test2 vertical'>
            <li data-id="1" data-name='Single Room' class='highlight'>Single Room<ol></ol></li>
            <li data-id="2" data-name='Double Room' class='highlight'>Double Room<ol></ol></li>
            <li data-id="3" data-name='Family Room' class='highlight'>Family Room<ol></ol></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <!--<button type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>-->
</form>
```

Javascript Code :

```
var oldContainer;
    var group = $("ol.test1").sortable({
      group: 'nested',
      afterMove: function (placeholder, container) {
        if(oldContainer != container){
          if(oldContainer)
            oldContainer.el.removeClass("active");
          container.el.addClass("active");

          oldContainer = container;
        }
      },
      onDrop: function ($item, container, _super) {

      var data = group.sortable("serialize").get();

      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, null, ' ');
      console.log(jsonString);
      $('#serialize_output').val(jsonString);

        container.el.removeClass("active");
        _super($item, container);
      }
    });

    $("ol.test2").sortable({
        group:  'nested',
        drop: false,
        drag: false,
    });
    $("ol.test2>li>ol").sortable({
        group:  'nested',
        drop: true,

    });

    $(".switch-container").on("click", ".switch", function  (e) {
      var method = $(this).hasClass("active") ? "enable" : "disable";
      $(e.delegateTarget).next().sortable(method);
    });
```

Demo is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/wyyzz9bt/2/

When I drag customer(box 1) to room type(box 2) like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7TZs.jpg, I check on the console, I just get the json data from box 1 (customer). I do not get json data from box 2 (room type).

How so that I can get the data json from box 2 (room type)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will have to initialize onDrop event binder for  $("ol.test2").sortable() as well.

Comment: You have two <ol> containers with class .test1 and .test2 respectively, you also have initialized them twice using .sortable, so to get results from .test2, u need to use onDrop for the second .test2 container as well.